# how to extract a vector figure from pdf

Tags: 13.10, pdf, latex

I have a question. I inserted my figure into my pdf file using latex in this way: I first created a vector figure using inkscape. Then I converted it to the pdf format and then included it to pdf using latex. Right now, using this generated PDF, I want to extract the previous svg figure. How can I extract it ?

BTW: I tried illustrator and also inkscape. However both required too many manual operations. I prefer the one which will take the pdf as input and output the svg figure. [image]

Answer (score 7):

You could try this:

```
inkscape yourFile.pdf --export-plain-svg=yourFile.svg
```

It will take the first page of the PDF and all the default import 
options.

You could also try [pdf2svg](http://www.pdftron.com/pdf2svg/index.html) to export svg file from pdf.

```
pdf2svg <input.pdf> <output.svg> [<pdf page no. or "all" >]
```

Answer (score 1):

`man pdftocairo`

```
NAME
       pdftocairo  - Portable Document Format (PDF) to PNG/JPEG/PDF/PS/EPS/SVG 
       using cairo

 SYNOPSIS
       pdftocairo [options] PDF-file [output-file]
```

Make sure that the required libraries listed above are available on your system.

```
sudo apt-get install python-poppler python texlive-extra-utils texlive
```

Now easily use :

```
pdftocairo -svg SomePDFfile.pdf
```

But if the pdf file contains more than single page you have then to explode then extract:

FIRST split this multipage pdf into its single pages

```
pdftk file.pdf burst
```

then use pdftocairo to convert any pdf page into svg

```
for f in *.pdf; do pdftocairo -svg $f; done
```

[some contents from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12084742/extracting-vector-graphics-from-pdf-with-inkscape)